# Do precipitous ideals "always" come from collapsing?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

It's well-known that if $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, then there is a poset $\mathbb{P}$ that forces $\kappa$ to carry a precipitous ideal.

Suppose that $\omega_1$ carries a preciptous ideal $I$.

It seems reasonable to wonder if there is always an inner model $N$ of the universe in which $\omega_1^V$ is measurable and for which there is a *set* $N$-generic $G$ that collapses $\omega^V_1$ and gives us $V=N[G]$.

The answer to this question is no. Using an argument of Reitz, we can add a *class* $V$-generic $H$ such that $V[H]$ satisfies the ground axiom and $V[H]$ still has a precipitous ideal on $\omega_1$. But $V[H]$ has no inner models that can access it by *set* forcing at all. A way of doing this to use the generic to code every set of ordinals cofinally in the continuum function.

Given this, I'd like to ask a different but perhaps related question.

Supposing still that $\omega_1$ has a precipitous ideal $I$, is it always the case that: there is a transitive model $N$ of, say, $ZFC^-$ with $Ord^N>\omega_1^V$ and an $N$-generic $G$ such that $N$ thinks $\omega_1^V$ is measurable and, say, $$V^{N[G]}_{\omega^V_1+2}=V_{\omega^V_1+2}?$$

Hopefully the intent here is clear. Feel free to reformulate if you see a mistake. Perhaps $ZFC^-$ is too strong or I'm asking for too much agreement and Reitz's theorem can still work. I haven't thought about that for long, but if it were the case, I'd like to consider weaker theories and less agreement. This has the feel of something folky, but I have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: Here's Jonas' paper for reference. See Thm 3.3. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609064

Comment: Instead of going to ZFC-, it would also make sense to ask for an inner model $N$ of ZFC, with all the ordinals, such that in $V$ there is an $N$-generic collapse $G$ of $\kappa=\omega_1^V$ (or more) such that $N[G]$ and $V$ agree on $P(\omega_1)$.

Comment: Yeah that's nice!

Comment: Have you looked at the situation when $V$ is the model of $\mathsf{MM}$ obtained the usual way from a supercompact?

Comment: Andrés, no not in this regard. Can you say more? I might email you.

Comment: Do you mean to put any restrictions on the forcing for which $G$ is generic? If not, assuming $M_1^\#$ exists and is fully iterable, I think there is a positive answer using the extender algebra. On the other hand, if you require that $G$ preserves $N$-cardinals above $\omega_1$, then the answer is probably negative under MM.

Comment: I hadn't meant any restrictions, but both suggestions are very welcome. My title is perhaps misleading. Maybe I should change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M_1^\#$ exists and is fully iterable, then there is an inner model $M$ in which $\omega_1$ is measurable and an $M$-generic $G$ such that $V_{\omega_1+2}\in M[G].$ Just iterate the first normal ultrafilter of $M_1$ so that its least measurable is shot up to $\omega_1$; call the resulting iterate $P$. Then do a genericity iteration of $P$ above $\omega_1$ to obtain an inner model $M$ such that $V_{\omega_1+2}$ is generic over $M$ for the extender algebra at its Woodin cardinal.

On the other hand, the answer to Joel's version of your question is *no* in the generic extension of $M_1$ where one Levy collapses the Woodin cardinal $\delta$ to become $\omega_2$. In this model $W$, there is a pre-saturated ideal on $\omega_1^W$. But suppose towards a contradiction $N$ is an inner model of $W$ such that $(V_{\omega_1+2})^W$ is generic over $N$ and $\omega_1^W$ is measurable in $N$. Since $M_1 = L[A]$ where $A\subseteq \delta$ and every $A\in P(\delta)\cap W$ is generic over $N$, we have that $M_1$ is contained in a generic extension of $N$. Therefore the mantle of $M_1$ is contained in $N$, and in particular by the Fuchs-Schindler analysis of the mantle of $M_1$, $\mathbb R^{M_1}\subseteq N$. This contradicts that $\omega_1^{M_1}$ is measurable in $N$.

Comment: Silly question: what is a "genericity iteration"?

Comment: Noah, see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4193

Comment: @TobyMeadows Thanks (that looks like a great paper btw, I'm separately happy to have it brought to my attention)!

Comment: Thanks Gabe! The first part's obvious to me (now), but I'll need to think more slowly on your OTOH. But this covers my question very nicely.

Comment: Yes there is a little problem in the second part that I'll try to fix later...

Comment: Noah, FWIW I think Steel's presentation in the handbook is more succinct and a little cleaner. But it only deals with adding reals. Gabe can be understood as using Theorem 4.5 from Farah's paper.

Comment: I gave up on the original $\text{ZFC}^-$ formulation of your question and just used Joel's, so maybe there's something going on there, maybe not. Also it seems interesting to ask about the situation when there is no inner model with a Woodin cardinal. I don't think it's known how to produce precipitous ideals without collapsing a measurable except using Woodin cardinals, so this makes this region particularly interesting for your question.